# How to convert (11,0,0) into time format

Tags: python

I got a dataframe with an array 'Time' of (11,0,0) and I want to convert it to dataframe 11:00:00
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this?

---------update-------------

```
import datetime as dt
length = len(df)
Time = []
DateTime = df['Time']
for n in range(0,length):
    Time.append(dt.time(*DateTime).strftime('%H-%M-%S'))
df['Time']=Time
```

error:function takes at most 6 arguments (4801 given)

Comment: `import datetime as dt` then `time = (11, 0, 1)` then `timestamp = dt.time(*time).strftime(%H-%M-%S')`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. however, this function only can take 6 arguments maximum. my array got 4801 element in this case. Do you know how can I iterate?

Comment: please see the update code in the question

Comment: You have only posted a screenshot. Is that an actual pandas dataframe? Please replace the image (which shouldn't be used because we can't copy/paste the code to test and it might age away) with some repeatable code so that I can test on my end. I don't fancy typing it out by hand, especially if I'm not sure that it's going to be in the correct format.

Comment: sure, i just want to create a function that convert df = {'Time' : [ '(11,0,0)', '(11,0,1)', '(11,0,2)', '(11,0,3)', '(11,0,4)', '(11,0,5)', '(11,0,6)','(11,0,7)']} into datetime format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to apply the transformation to a single column. You can unpack the tuple into a [`datetime.time`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) object and then `strftime` it back into the format you want.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3], 'Time': [(11, 0, 0), (11, 0, 1), (15, 2, 3)]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def return_time(input_tuple):
    return dt.time(*input_tuple).strftime('%H-%M-%S')

df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(return_time)
```